# Mongodb. JWT: how to create JWT using TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I am a beginner and I am trying to implement **JWT** in **express.js**  **login** endpoint. The error I get, comes from **typescript**, I guess. It says, that the type of **jwt secret token** is a  wrong type.
Here is my error

```
Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Secret'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Secret'.
```

I tried multiple ways, but didn't work. And what is weird, that in import I've a warning, that ****JWT_SECRET** is defined but never used**
Unfortunately I can't figure out how to solve it. I assume that my first argument is also wrong, even though it doesn't throw errors.

Here is the code

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import JsonWebToken from 'jsonwebtoken' 

import { Products, Users } from '../models'
import UserService from '../services/Users'

import { JWT_SECRET } from '../util/secrets' //JWT_SECRET** is defined but never used

import {
  NotFoundError,
  BadRequestError,
  InternalServerError,
} from '../helpers/apiError'

// POST /users
export const register= async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const { firstName, lastName, password, email } = req.body
    const emailExists = await UserService.findUserByEmail(email)
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 8)

    if (emailExists) {
      next(new BadRequestError('Email already exists'))
    } else {
      const user = new Users({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        password: hashedPassword,
        email,
      })

      await UserService.create(user)

      res.json(user)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (!bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, req.body.email)) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'The password is invalid' })
    } else {
      next(new InternalServerError('Internal Server Error', error))
    }
  }
}

export const logInUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    if (email) {
      const result = await UserService.findUserByEmail(email).then(
        async (user) => {
          if (!user) res.status(404).json({ message: 'email not found' })
          else {
            const logInSuccess = await bcrypt.compare(password, user!.password)
            logInSuccess ? user : res.status(404).json('Incorrect password')
            return user
          }
          const users = await Users.findOne(email)
          const token = JsonWebToken.sign({ users }, process.env.JWT_SECRET) // the error is here for 2nd argument
          res.json({ token })
        }
      )
      return res.status(200).json({ result, message: 'logIn successfully' })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: 'user not found' })
  }
}
```

Please help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `JWT_SECRET` instead of `process.env.JWT_SECRET`

Comment: @Mike S thanks for help. Now it works. One more question, please. How can I see token in postman? When I login for now, it doesn't show up

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to obtain. :)